# Could not create the driver from NHibernate.Driver.OracleDataClientDriver Version=4.030319

Tags: .net, oracle, nhibernate, windows-server-2016, system.data.oracleclient

I have been battling with this for last few days and I am at my wits end!

My project have moved to a new development environment coming from Server 2008 to Server 2016. The application uses .Net Framework 4.0, Oracle Client win32_11gR2 and NHibernate 4.030319. Now of course this all works wonderfully on Server 2008 R2, but on Server 2016, we are not able to get things to work.

Whilst I do appreciate that the 11g version of Oracle needs .Net Framework 3.5 to be installed, but because we are not in charge of the actual operating system this is under control of our support guys, we tried the 12c version of the client. This installed ok, but when we tried calling the application, it errored with "Could not create the driver from NHibernate.Driver.OracleDataClientDriver".

I have tried putting in the machine.config setting for Database Factories, but nothing seems to make this work since moving to Server 2016.

Does anyone know how to get this to work on Windows Server 2016?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work after getting the .Net Framework 3.5 installed via add features. For my benefit it will work with the 64 bit version. Ignore during the installation the message that says that your environment does not meet minimum requirements.